# simple regex expression quandry

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like `test_validation_v4_0_1-f` that I would like to split into 2 pieces: `test_validation` and `4_0_1-f`, the best I've gotten so far is:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'_v(\d+)')
print r.split('test_validation_v4_0_1-f')
```

The results are:

```
['test_validation', '4', '_0_1-f']
```

The result I want is:

```
['test_validation', '4_0_1-f']
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one will do for you. It will check for digits ahead but will not pick in expression.

```
r = re.compile(r'_v(?=\d+)')
```

Comment: I would have gone with r = re.compile(r'_v(\d*)') but that gives three  elements in the array.  Have to learn more about assertions.  Thanks